# Get facebook post made by my application and the number of likes/comments on it

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook application that I use to post messages on user's wall. I save the post id. I want to know the number of likes and comments on each of these posts? 
Do I need a read_stream permission to access my own posts? 
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need read_stream permission from the user to be able to read the post since the user owns their own status update (and its likes/comments), not your application.  If you have read_stream, you can then just access /postID via the Graph API.

Comment: how do I fetch likes and comments if I have given read_stream permission.?